# Is it possible to call an object in C#?

Tags: c#, object

Is it possible to call a class instance in C#?
For example, is it possible to do this?

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass();
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: What do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, functions can be stored as objects. These are called delegates in .NET.

So if you have something that's of type  i.e. a delegate like `Func` or `Action` or such that would work, you can call it. I don't believe this is possible for arbitrary classes.

For example:

```
Func<int, int> doubleIt = (x) => x * 2;
doubleIt(4); 

//or
Action<Object> print = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
print(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your goal with this but you can do something like this:

```
Func<MyClass> myClass = () => new MyClass();

// Then you can call this function, which returns a new instance of 'MyClass'
MyClass newInstance = myClass();
```